# MVC 3 razor DropDown for foreign keys and new Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I can't find a sample with this simple problem.
I have 2 tables Books and Authors with a foreign key on AuthorID.
I need to be able to add a book with an author and that author to be inserted with the foreign key relation.

Is it possible from an create view and controller in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

These are models:

```
   namespace CiksAyna.Data.Model
    {
        [TableName("tbl_book")]
        [PrimaryKey("book_id", autoIncrement = true)]
        public class Book
        {
            [Column("book_id")]
            public int BookId { get; set; }

            [Column("author_id")]
            public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace CiksAyna.Data.Model
    {
        [TableName("tbl_author")]
        [PrimaryKey("author_id", autoIncrement = true)]
        public class Author
        {
            [Column("author_id")]
            public int AuthorId { get; set; }

            [Column("author_name")]
            public int AuthorName { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

In view page

```
@model CiksAyna.Data.Model.Book


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Books</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Authors, "AuthorId", "AuthorName"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorId)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

In controller

```
    public  ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Authors = GetAllAuthors();

        return View();
    }

   public List<Author> GetAllAuthors()
        {
            return Db.From("tbl_author").ToList<Author>();
        }
```

Comment: The question was about Inserting new books. I can't insert new books only with existing authors. I've replaced the DropDown from create view with an EditorFor but I can't get the AuthorID when inserting.